# How do Mathematica processes DynamicBox?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, stylesheet, kernel, boxes

I've heard that Mathematica uses a session ad hoc to process `DynamicBox`, but I don't know any detail. I am using `DynamicBox` in stylesheets and sometimes I can't understand its behavior: when it is updated, what difference can be produced when it's placed as `CellFrameLabel` etc.

Comment: This is entirely implemented by the front end and is so mostly undocumented, but basically there are two modes in which evaluation can occur: in the first the FE calls back into the kernel to run code and in the second it runs the code on its own. Whenever possible try to write your interface to do the second as that tends to perform significantly better.

Comment: DynamicBox is what Dynamic is typeset to so the first question is, are you familiar with `Dynamic` documentation / tutorials?

Comment: @Kuba I've read the tutorials.  However, when I tried to provide my example for the strange behavior of `DynamicBox` just now, I found a new interpretation which has nothing to do with `DynamicBox`. That's my fault. Leave this question alone. You can talk about the general properties of `DynamicBox` here and there isn't any specific trouble any more.

Comment: @Kuba Finally, I think the trouble can be summarized as: `DynamicBox` with `Refresh` does not update `CounterBox`. It seems that the only thing can update `CounterBox` is any modification of cells.